# Clarifications on MDN "Use functions instead of evaluating snippets of code" - why's that?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout, eval

On MDN article about `eval` there's a paragraph titled [Use functions instead of evaluating snippets of code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#use_functions_instead_of_evaluating_snippets_of_code), in the example code there's a reference about setTimeout(). I can't grasp why this advice/command, so, keeping the setTimeout() reference, could someone point me out why these codes work as expected:

```
function timedPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(( ) => {resolve(console.log('Promise resolved!'))}, 1000)
  })
};
 
function timedPromise2(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function(){resolve(console.log('Another promise resolved!'))}, 2000)
  })
};
timedPromise();
timedPromise2();
/*output:
Promise {<pending>}
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
Promise resolved! //after at least 1s
Another promise resolved! //after at least 2s
*/
```

While this code won't?

```
function timedPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve(console.log('I resolved!')), 1000)
  })
};
 
timedPromise();
/*output:
I resolved! //immediate
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
*/
```

I understand the browser evaluates the code snippet as a `string` instead of a function, and then interprets it and executes it immediately instead of waiting for the delay of setTimeout() to pass.

Why though?

Why/when should I use wrapper functions instead of code snippets as parameters? Is it a thing related only to asynchronicity?

Comment: basically: "lazy evaluation" or "deferred evaluation". Javascript engine must _evaluate_ the code present. If this code does side effects (like printing on the console), then this is done immediately. But you want something to be triggered later, like "ow, this argument to my function` is some code to execute _later_, when the function sees fit, not right now!" then the pattern is to use a wrapping function. This has equivalent in most programming languages.

Comment: The trick is, javascript can evaluate the code immediately as "another function that will do something when called". So you the inside code in the wrapped function is _not_ immediately executed.

Comment: Thanks Pac0,
I like the thinking "wrap it, if you want to defer it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `functionName()`, the `()` call the function immediantly.

So when you write `setTimeout(resolve(console.log('I resolved!')), 1000)` it:

- Calls `console.log` first to pass its return value into `resolve`;
- Calls `resolve` to pass it's value into `setTimeout`;
- Calls `setTimeout`.

---

When you wrap a function in a lambda, you're passing a *reference* to that function through, rather than calling it immediantly. It might be clearer to see like this:

```js
function doLog() { console.log("Hello, world!"); }

// Calls doLog instantly, passes in return value of undefined
setTimeout(doLog(), 1000); 

// Passes in a reference to doLog, which setTimeout will then call later
setTimeout(doLog, 1000);
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. So the "Use functions instead of evaluating snippets of code" is just related to the fact that code snippets in that case are evaluated immediately instead of being deferred?